# Adding image to Xaml button breaks Xamarin app, but Visual Studio gives no error message

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

In Xaml, I'm trying to make an image do something when tapped (I'm testing it on Android). The `Image` tag of the `Button` class seems to be exactly what I need, but the following code breaks my application:

```
<Button Clicked="OnListClicked" Image="chimp.jpg"/>
```

Even though it works fine when I remove the `Image` tag. I could probably figure out what's wrong if I had an error message, but all that is shown is:

```
Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).
```

I've had issues with my Xaml code before, and I would get the same message. I'm confused though...my Xaml isn't external, is it? It's just a Xaml file inside my shared project, like any other file.

Under Exception Settings, I have every single box checked, and I also added XamlCompilation:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace MyApp
{...
```

so I'm not sure what else I can do to start getting error messages. And I'm using `Image` in exactly the syntax described in the documentation, so I'm not sure what could be the issue with my Xaml. Anyone have any thoughts about any of this?

Comment: Try enabling XAML Compilation to see if it gives you a better error when building the project. Add the following above a namespace in a single place to enable it for all XAML pages: `[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` or do it above a class without the `assembly:` part to enable it for a single page.

Comment: @hvaughan3 I added that, but I'm still getting the same "there is no code to show" error message.

Comment: Ca you post the code behind too?

Comment: When your application hits the break mode, hit the "Continue" button once more, and it will most likely spit out the actualy error code. Tell me if it worked. I assume your chimp.jpg does not exists / is not in Resources/drawable-mdpi or any other drawable folder

Comment: @Csharpest I kind of figured it out, I just had to set the page with errors as my root page, and now I get error messages. Apparently my runtime runs out of memory after 5 pictures, but I'm not sure if it's supposed to.

Comment: This might come from you not disposing the image streams. try searching for optimal image usage in xamarin, there are many helpful tips on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I wasn't getting a specific error message was that I was actually navigating to the page with the errors from another page. When I set the page with errors to my root page, I started getting error messages again.

Apparently, my runtime's memory was running out before it could render the image. I had noticed before that my app was limited to five images: any images after the fifth one simply didn't show up. I've never gotten an error for it, though. Perhaps since this time it was a button, it "needs" to be displayed for normal functioning, and that's why it's throwing an error this time?

Either way, I just removed images until there were only 5, including the button image, and now it displays without issue. I'm not sure if this is expected behavior, though. I don't see why my runtime wouldn't be able to handle more than 5 images.